# Using a variable in an IN clause in sql server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pass in a variable in the IN clause and in googling for solutions I did the following but getting errors.  Any help and/or direction would be appreciated.

My code is listed first then the errors are found below.

My code:

```
DECLARE @OwnerSysID varchar(500)
SET @OwnerSysID = '3, 3476, 3511'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'Select AllPosiable.UserID, AllPosiable.AgentSysID, 0' + 
            'From (' +
                'Select AgentSysID, UserID' + 
                'From (' +
                    'Select AGT_Agent.AgentSysID' +
                    'From AGT_Agent' +
                    'Where OwnerSysID IN ('+@OwnerSysID+')' +
                    'AND AgentName NOT LIKE %Texas State Low Cost%' +
                    'AND AgentName NOT LIKE %TSLC%' +
                    ') as AgentIDs ' +
                'Full Join (' +
                    'Select DISTINCT IW_UserAgentRelationship.UserID' +
                    'From AGT_Agent' +
                    'Left Join IW_UserAgentRelationship' +
                    'On IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID = AGT_Agent.AgentSysID' +
                    'Where OwnerSysID IN ('+@OwnerSysID+')' +
                    'And IW_UserAgentRelationship.isDefault = 1' +
                    'AND AgentName NOT LIKE %Texas State Low Cost%' + 
                    'AND AgentName NOT LIKE %TSLC%' +
                ') As UserIDs On 1=1' +
            ') as AllPosiable' +
            'Left Join IW_UserAgentRelationship' +
            'On IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID = AllPosiable.AgentSysID' +
            'And IW_UserAgentRelationship.UserID = AllPosiable.UserID' +
            'Where IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID Is NULL' 

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'OwnerSysID'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Join'.
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you print @sql, you will notice that there are not spaces in some lines. For example  'Select AGT_Agent.AgentSysID' + 'From AGT_Agent'

Comment: Have you tried to `PRINT @sql` to see what the statement looks like???  If you haven't, do it.  Then you'll probably find out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's time and help.  It is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) instead of a comma-delimited string for `@OwnerSysID`? That would allow you to build predicates that use a variable number of arguments without having to resort to dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

That's not passing a variable to the IN() clause. It's straight-up injection-vulnerable string concatenation, so be **very** careful how you use it.

But the issue is here:

```
SET @sql = 'Select AllPosiable.UserID, AllPosiable.AgentSysID, 0' + 
            'From (' +
```

There's no whitespace in the string after the `0` at the end of the first line, no whitespace before the word `From` at the beginning of the second line, and the line break between them *is not part of the resulting string*. You end up with this:

```
Select AllPosiable.UserID, AllPosiable.AgentSysID, 0From (...
```

Try this:

```
SET @sql = 'Select AllPosiable.UserID, AllPosiable.AgentSysID, 0' + 
            ' From (' +
```

and make sure you're doing something similar at every line break.

Additionally, you need to look at this excerpt:

```
'AND AgentName NOT LIKE %Texas State Low Cost%' +
```

The expression `%Texas State Low Cost%` will not be part of a string literal in the resulting SQL code. You need to do this:

```
 'AND AgentName NOT LIKE ''%Texas State Low Cost%''' +
```

and, again, make sure all of the string literals in the SQL statement get similar treatment.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems in your query.  Try this:

```
SET @sql = N'  -- strings should nvarchar for sp_executesql
Select AllPosiable.UserID, AllPosiable.AgentSysID, 0
From (Select AgentSysID, UserID
      From (Select AGT_Agent.AgentSysID
            From AGT_Agent
            Where OwnerSysID IN (@OwnerSysID) and
                  AgentName NOT LIKE ''%Texas State Low Cost%'' and
                  AgentName NOT LIKE ''%TSLC%''
           ) AgentIDs Full Join
           (Select DISTINCT IW_UserAgentRelationship.UserID
            From AGT_Agent Left Join
                 IW_UserAgentRelationship
                 On IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID = AGT_Agent.AgentSysID
            Where OwnerSysID IN (@OwnerSysID) and
                  IW_UserAgentRelationship.isDefault = 1 and
                  AgentName NOT LIKE ''%Texas State Low Cost%'' and
                  AgentName NOT LIKE ''%TSLC%''
           ) UserIDs
           On 1 = 1
      ) AllPosiable Left Join
      IW_UserAgentRelationship
      On IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID = AllPosiable.AgentSysID and
         IW_UserAgentRelationship.UserID = AllPosiable.UserID
Where IW_UserAgentRelationship.AgentID Is NULL
' ;

SET @sql = replace(@sql, n'@OwnerSysID', @OwnerSysID)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Your basic problem is not understanding that a string can span multiple lines in SQL Server.  That means that you don't have to concatenate a bunch of different lines together.  In your case, you are merging together keywords, so the SQL is not understandable.  If you had printed out `@sql`, this would be obvious.

Another problem is that the `like` patterns are not surrounded by single quotes.  Within a string, these need to be duplicated.

I didn't look at the logic of the query itself, but I really doubt that `full join` is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're taking the dynamic sql route just because you need to pass @OwnerSysID as a comma separated values to put it inside the `IN()`

if that is the case, then use TVF to pass a variable with a comma separated values without using the dynamic sql.

I've mentioned this method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434227/sending-same-parameter-twice-in-exec/52434860#52434860)

Basically, what you need is a Table Valued function that will handle @OwnerSysID to convert its values to rows (with the help of XML technique), then use it inside `IN()`

Needed Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split(@String VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) MyString
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@String,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) MyString
    ) D
    CROSS APPLY MyString.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
)
```

then you can use it in your query like this :

```
OwnerSysID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@OwnerSysID))
```

With this method, you don't need the dynamic sql, just a normal query will be enough.

Comment: I'm actually looking at this option as it was mentioned earlier.  Thank you.

Comment: This is the crux of the problem - all the other answers are related to formatting, spaces etc which need doing, but will all eventually lead to the problem answered here.